# How to use Entity Framework in Enterprise application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-design, ado.net

i have some questions of how to use the Entity Framework in an enterprise application.

First of all, i work with ADO.NET for many years now and i use objects to reflect the data that i get from the database provider.
Every time i want to change something or insert something into the database.

I just call a Save() method and get the job done.
Every object has a `DatabaseManager` that manage the queries to the `DataAccess` layer.
For example

```
public class Article{
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string Title{get;set;}
   .....
   public bool Save(){
         if(this.ID == -1){
            return new ArticleDatabaseManager().InsertArticle(this);
         }else{
            return new ArticleDatabaseManager().UpdateArticle(this);
         }
   }
}
public ArticleDatabaseManager : DatabaseManager
{
   ...ADO.NET code
}
```

---

I don't know if i have to use the same architectur or change all the way i use this objects in my application.

I thought if i create something like the above i can do something like this :

```
public class Article{
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public string Title{get;set;}
   .....
   public bool Save(){
         if(this.ID == -1){
            return new ArticleDatabaseManager().InsertArticle(this);
         }else{
            return new ArticleDatabaseManager().UpdateArticle(this);
         }
   }
}
```

In the Each DatabaseManager implements some Link To Entities or even EntitySQL to do the same job like the old DatabaseManager does.
Fill the Business models with the values that i from the Entity Objects.
Then i could work with the Business as before and just any time i want to do some changes i communicate via EntityFramework to the Database.

Sould i implement something like the above?

Sould i just inherit the previous business objects to the entity objects?

EX :

```
  public class Article : ArticleEntity
  {
     //some properties for validation etc 
  }
```

Sould i use something completely different?
I Just Don't knwo:/

I have no experience with other ORM. Just mine hand written "ORM" System.

Thank you very much.
I'm sorry for my lack of English and i know that i ask too much in a single question...
But moving from one technology to an other for a dinosaur like me is like i change Country:/

Comment: You should only ask one question in each post. Move the "THIS IS DATABASE..." section off to another question.

Comment: I'm sorry but i was thinking that this question arise from the entity framework navigation. I removed it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you at least try to use some EF tutorial? If not it is time to do that because we cannot explain you everything about EF in single answer (even in multiple - that is not purpose of SO to replace tutorials and learning materials). That should give you pretty clear answer about all your stuff related to your database managers.

In general what you did till know is very close to Active record pattern. If your objects also has static methods used to retrieve object from database it is Active record pattern. When using EF you usually don't use this pattern and you don't need any database manager. EF is build around class which is called context and this context works as your database manager for all entities you are using. It is possible to add saving and retrieval methods to entities but because it breaks separation of concerns and it makes your entities heavily dependent on EF and persistence (trend is to make them completely independent = POCO) it is usually not used.

Don't derive any custom class from entity. EF will not be able to use your derived type. Use entity mapped in EF as your class and add all custom properties and methods directly to this class (you can even create that class from scratch if you don't want to use code generators). In case of generated entities you can add custom code in partial classes. If you don't use EF entity as your object you will have to manually handle conversion from one to other (or use some tool like AutoMapper).

EF is not able to work with XML column - it will handle it as string. Especially if you plan to use these data for some ordering or filtering and if they have fixed structure you should model them as separate tables / entities. If it is really just structured content (with dynamic structure) you can use it as XML string.

Comment: Yes i have read EF Tutorials and books about the framework.
But i got a lot confused. Thats why I asked here.
And despite the fact that you were ironic at first you gave me a very nice answer.
Thank you a lot:)

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8/sourcecode?fileId=25232&pathId=1337828505

This is a "right" use of EntityFramework, because i see that it uses a DAL.
Thank you